# Android onTouchEvent won't work while DatagramSocket is receiving

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm trying to allow my user to move a block around a screen while also listening for connected on a DatagramSocket, here is my onTouchEvent

```
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event )
{
    if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
    {
        if( event.getY() > getHeight() - 50 )
        {
            gameState.setRunning( false );
            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
        }
        else
        {
            touched = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
        }
        checkCollisions( event.getX(), event.getY() );
    }

    if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
    {
        checkCollisions( event.getX(), event.getY() );
    }

    if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) 
    {
        touched = false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

And here is my server code

```
public void run()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Ip address used:" + getLocalIPAddress() );
    while( true )
    {
        //Receive some data
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
        try 
        {
            socket.receive( packet );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );

        Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + data);

    }
}
```

Now my server works fine, but while the server is waiting for a connection, the client can't do anything, now I know a thread could be started, but won't that still block the onTouchEvent?

Canvas

Update

I implemented the run as a doInBackground using AsyncTask, it now works fine now without a problem, i can play with my application and also wait for clients to connect, this should work fine, Cheers for the help people.

Canvas

Comment: If they're on the same thread, you're definitely in trouble. If they're on different threads, you stand some chance ...

Comment: Well my server is on a thread, but not the onTouchEvent, how would i go about putting the onTouchEvent on a thread? the android OS runs the function onTouchEvent when the screen is touched, how can i implement that into a run method?

Comment: You must not place the `onTouchEvent` method in a thread. You should place your listening server in its own thread instead.

Comment: Yes, the onTouchEvent should stay where it is unless it has a lot to do. In this case you want to have the anything to do with connections on a separate thread. Perhaps it should run in an AsyncTask?

Comment: well at the moment, the application has no threads, but the server is a thread, how would I go about making the onTouchEvent a thread? if i made the class extends thread, that won't do much

Comment: If i was to create a class that deals with drawing and touching, while one class deals with the server, this would stop the problem yea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need a bit more space than a comment ...

Key point: creating classes doesn't create threads, unless they are thread extending classes (`AsyncTask`, `Thread`, etc).

Typically for your application the server would run in one thread, the game logic in another, the image updater in a third and the UI thread would refresh the display from this third thread when told that there was a new thing to display.

An example of a similar approach is given in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-basic-game_05.html. I would suggest using that as a starting point and adding in an extra Server thread on a similar basis, which should get things going.

Sorry if I'm telling you stuff you already know, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: No I understand threads, I just can't get my head around how I can implement it in my project, looking at the example, it seems quite helpful, but I did just find AsyncTask which Neil Townsend, I think this maybe a better way for me to send UDP packets and receive them.

Comment: OOhh neil, that is the tutorial i Used :), but when i start a new thread, it kinda stops all the others :(, i will take another look at my code, i can also provide it if needed

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you built a new version of your project with just the key classes and threads and checked they were working as expected using the Log function. Once it seems they are working, add in functionality bit at a time and see what is going on. Out of interest, how are you starting the thread?

Answer (score 1):

In Android, every [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) related aspects should be handled in the main thread, that is, the UI thread. Time consuming, heavy calculations or simple blocking tasks  should remain in an another thread to avoid the user interface to be frozen.

Taking care of keeping your user interface fluid and responsive is important. If you don't, the [`ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) will certainly end up popping up an alert box asking the user if he would like to close you application as it is not responding properly to his interactions. This called an `ANR` (Application not responding).

You might want to read this [very good article](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) talking about the *responsiveness* of every  application should guarantee. It is written by the Google Android team and contains a *lot* of precious advises.